# Xcode 4.3.2: Can not add files outside the project folder

Tags: xcode4.3

I have just upgraded to XCode 4.3.2 and now my old projects are not correctly loaded. All files outside the project folder are displayed in red color. The folder structure is like this:

- MyLibFiles

  - mylibfile.h
- MyProject

  - MyProject.xcodeproj
  - anysource.h
  - alias of mylibfile.h

So I can't add "mylibfile.h" to the project. It's simply impossible. It's also impossible to add the file via an alias ("alias of mylibfile.h").

Currently the only way is to make a copy of "MyLibFiles" into "MyProject". But that can not be the way, it's silly.

Comment: Same problem here. Xcode does not want to include aliased files. As you said, it's silly.

Comment: Command+N to create a new file with the same name as the one you need. Exit Xcode and replace that file with the alias of the file you need. Open Xcode.